# List views of Custom Object not displaying in Changesset for deployment

Tags: deployment

I am unable to see the List view which i have created for custom object in outbound changeset.Kinldy suggest some solution to deploy the list view. I dnt want to deploy through workbench

Answer (score 3):

By default List view is available for change set.

Scenario below may cause the list view is not visible:

1. Check the Filter Criteria of that List View. Confirm that List View is not filtered by a Queue. Even you can deploy Queues as component, but any object referencing a Queue cannot be moved through Packaging or Change Sets.
2. Check the Visibility of the List View. Confirm it is either Visible to all users (Includes partner and customer portal users) or Visible to certain groups of users. List View Visible only to me will be not visible in Outbound Change Set component.

So make sure you are not running in any of the above scenario.

[Components Available in Change Sets](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=changesets_about_components.htm&type=5)

Comment: Tushar, my scenario is i dnt have any queue and also my visiblitiy is  Visible to certain groups of users. i dnt have any crieteria

Comment: @VinothiniMurugesh can you check maybe they are already added.

Comment: No , it has not added Tushar.   This is the 1st time we are trying to add

Comment: @VinothiniMurugesh not sure will work but can check if object status is deployed and not "In development"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Queues and these Queues are referencing to any object, this cant be added Change Sets.

Refer: Components Available in Change Sets :
 [https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets_about_components.htm&language=en]

Solution is you will have to manually recreate them.

Comment: my scenario is i dnt have any queue and also my visiblitiy is Visible to certain groups of users. i dnt have any crieteria

Answer (score 0):

Check Your visibility Criteria 
By default, list views are visible to all users when you deploy a change set. You can deploy a change set with Restricted Visibility, or change the visibility in the destination org if necessary.

Comment: we tried by adding visible to all users. Eventhough it has not visible in changeset